# How to get location for one time in ios

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, cllocation

How to fetch the location for only one time in ios app.

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: Let us know the issue you are facing right now?

Comment: It may be the case the OP just wants to share his/her solution. In this case, he/she should post it as a QA: post a question stating the original issue, and then post an answer with his/her proposed solution, rather than both problem statement and solution in the question.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference in the time taken to get an accurate location using `requestLocation` and using calls to `didUpdateLocations` if you reject the initial inaccurate locations

Comment: thank you guys. @jcaron you were right. I wrote this to provide the solution rather than asking the question.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes you are right but here we are fetching the location for only one time. so it's taking considerable amount of time

Answer (score 3):

After getting your location, stop update location manager and also release locationManager because you don't need locationManager anymore.

```
[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
self.locationManager = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

In ios 9 and above we have a method `[locationManagerInstance requestLocation]`. But this will take almost ten secs to call back the delegate methods since the location is latest and best.

In another way (for earlier ios9 versions), you could still use the old method [locationManagerInstance startUpdatingLocation] to get the immediate location and also you could validate the timestamp for the best accuracy.

Here is the code that I'm using for getting the location. Create a global reference for locationManager instance.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
```

Implement these utility methods in your.m file

```
-(BOOL)canUseLocationManager{
    if(([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) || ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways)){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

-(void) getCurrentLocation {
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    // ios 9 and above versions only 
    //[locationManager requestLocation]; // This may take more time when compare to alternate method
    // ios 2 and later versions can use this method
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void) stopGettingCurrentLocation {
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Implement location service delegates

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status{
    if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined){
        [self doneCheckingAccessStatusForLocation];
    }
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    locationManager.delegate = nil; 
    /* Clean the locationManager instance if you don't need*/
    //locationManager = nil;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    locationManager.delegate = nil;

    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;

    /* Implement your business logics here */
    /* Clean the locationManager instance if you don't need*/
    //locationManager = nil;
}
```

Final methods to create the location manager instance and initiate fetching location

```
-(void)checkForLocationService{
    if(!locationManager){
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    }
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined){
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }else{
        [self doneCheckingAccessStatusForLocation];
    }

}

-(void)doneCheckingAccessStatusForLocation{
    if([self canUseLocationManager]){
        [self getCurrentLocation];
    }
}
```

call the checkForLocationService method and implement your logics on the success and failure delegate methods.

```
[self checkForLocationService];
```